# Merging two csv files into list of dictionaries

Tags: python, csv

i have a task to do and i got stuck because whatever i do it does't seem to work.

So i have to csv files.
First called persons_file and it contains header line: id, name, surname.
And visits_file containing id, person_id, site.
I have to write a function called merge that gets to files as arguments (both StrionIO type) and returns list of dictionaries with number of visits for each users:

```
[ {
 "id": (person's id),
 "name": (person's name),
 "surname": (person's surname),
 "visits": (number of visits)
 } ]
```

I came up with this and i don't know where my mistake is.

```
import io

def merge(persons_file,visits_file):
    line_counter = 0
    return_list = []
    list_of_person_ids = []
    visits = 0

    for row in visits_file:
        if line_counter == 0:
            line_counter+=1
            continue
        list_of_person_ids.append(row.split(',')[1])

    line_counter = 0

    for row in persons_file:
        if line_counter == 0:
            line_counter+=1
            continue
        help_dict = {}
        split_row = row.split(',')
        help_dict['id'] = split_row[0]
        help_dict['name'] = split_row[1]
        help_dict['surname'] = split_row[2][:len(split_row[2])-1]
        if split_row[0] in list_of_person_ids:
            visits = list_of_person_ids.count(split_row[0])
        help_dict['visits'] = str(visits)
        return_list.append(help_dict)
        visits=0
    return return_list

file1 = open('persons_file.csv' , mode='r')
file2 = open('visits_file.csv' , mode='r')
persons_file_arg = io.StringIO(file1.read())
visits_file_arg = io.StringIO(file2.read())

list_of_visits = merge(persons_file_arg,visits_file_arg)
for i in list_of_visits:
    print(i)
file1.close()
file2.close()
```

I will be glad if anyone could help me.

Comment: Can you provide examples of the first few lines of the two files?

Comment: Can you use pandas?

Answer (score 0):

What is the issue? Is it the output that is not what you expected, or are you getting an exception? Your code seems like it should achieve the result you want, but I have a couple suggestions to make that could simplify things.

1. Look into `collections.Counter` you could then call `count_of_visits_by_person_id = Counter(list_of_person_ids)` to get a result of the form:
   `{person_id: number_of_visits, ...}`. You could then use this to simply look up the number of visits in your next for loop. e.g.:

```
from collections import Counter

...

count_of_visits_by_person_id = Counter(list_of_person_ids)

for row in persons_file:
    if line_counter == 0:
        line_counter += 1
        continue

    help_dict = {}
    split_row = row.split(',')

    help_dict['id'] = split_row[0]
    help_dict['name'] = split_row[1]
    help_dict['surname'] = split_row[2][:-1]  
   # [:len(split_row[2]) - 1] is equivalent to [:-1]
   # I assume you are stripping whitespace from the right side,
   # which can also be accomplished using split_row[2].rstrip()

    if split_row[0] in count_of_visits_by_person_id:
        visits = count_of_visits_by_person_id[split_row[0]]
    else:
        visits = 0
    help_dict['visits'] = str(visits)

    return_list.append(help_dict)
```

2. The generally simpler and safer way to open files is using the `with` statement. Here is an example:

```
with open('visits_file.csv', mode='r') as visits_file:
   row = visits_file.readline()
   while row:
       row = visits_file.readline()  # Skips the first line
       list_of_person_ids.append(row.split(',')[1])
```

Comment: When i'm pasting my code in website where it should be verified i'm getting error message. The only feedback i got was that i'm using tuples insted of dictionaries. But i'm not or at least i think. And thank you for your suggestion really appreciate.

Comment: Yeah, I don't see any tuples in there. Could you post a way for us to test your code?